# Pywinauto waiting too long to do an action

Tags: python, user-interface, automation, pywinauto

I need help.

I'm doing a UI automation, and it works properly.

However, it waits for all controls get done, but for example, the textbox I want to send keys is activated.

Because of that, my automation is very slow, and I couldn't find any helpful information in module documentation.

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out the solution. If you have the same problem, you should always search for controls, with child_window function.

If you use the bracket notation, pywiauto will search all controls from root window, and depending the application, it takes a long time.

However, using child window, you can filter by control type, title and automation id

Answer (score 0):

Global timings for every operation can be changed in module `pywinauto.timings`:

- https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.timings.html

But please be careful. Aggressive timings can make some actions unstable.

Comment: I read that documentation, but I didn’t any example of how to apply it